# bootstrap tab not working in bootstrap mega menu

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, menu, tabs

I'm developing a website using bootstrap but with one problem:

In my website, I have a mega menu using yamm3, and my mega menu have tabs in it just like cisco site: cisco.com -> menu -> products & services.

Everything works perfect but one thing: I design my mega menu to be fixed when scrolling and my problem happens just at this point. When I click on tabs, the status of clicked tab become "active" but the content doesn't show.

Here is my code:

```
 <!-- Menu -->
  <div class="row">
    <div id="nav"> 
    <nav class="navbar yamm navbar-default">
      <div class="container">
        <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
        <div class="navbar-header">
          <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
            <span class="sr-only">menubar</span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          </button>
          <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">home</a>
        </div>
        <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
          <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
            <li class="dropdown">
              <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-expanded="false">menu item 1<span class="caret"></span></a>
              <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
                <li>
                  <div class="row">
                    <!-- Tab panes -->
                    <div class="tab-content">
                      <div role="tabpanel" class="row tab-pane fade in active" id="home">
                          some data
                      </div>
                      <div role="tabpanel" class="row tab-pane fade" id="profile">
                            example data
                      </div>
                      <div role="tabpanel" class="row tab-pane fade" id="messages">
                          something goes here
                      </div>
                    </div>
                      <!-- Nav tabs -->
                    <ul class="nav nav-tabs main-menu" role="tablist">
                      <li role="presentation" class="active"><a href="#home" aria-controls="home" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">something</a></li>
                      <li role="presentation"><a href="#profile" aria-controls="profile" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">data</a></li>
                      <li role="presentation"><a href="#messages" aria-controls="messages" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">اitem</a></li>
                    </ul>
                  </div>
                </li>
              </ul>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </div><!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
      </div><!-- /.container-fluid -->
    </nav>
    </div>
  </div><!-- End of menu -->
```

and the code for fixing my menu on scrolling using "STICKY ANYTHING - JQUERY PLUGIN":

```
$('#nav').stickThis({
    minscreenwidth:768
});
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Without seeing your CSS it's really not possible to see the problem.

Comment: This is not about css. everything works but one thing: a javascript code: when fixing the menu, tabs don't work.

Comment: You don't need javascript to make the navbar fixed.

Comment: So how can I make the navbar fixed? with "navbar-fixed-top"? I don't need my navbar to be fixed in first place, I want my navbar to be sticky after scrolling

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add this to the element you want to **Affix** and change `data-offset-top` to your height requirement.

```
data-spy="affix" data-offset-top="100"
```

Add this to your CSS and adjust it to the element you put the above code inside.

```
nav.affix {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%;
    z-index: 10;
}
```

If you **only** want the Affix to be applied on a mobile viewport then the CSS is as follows.

This rule keeps you desktop view from becoming affixed.

```
nav.affix {
    position: static;
}
```

This rule will Affix the navbar based on the **media rule** you apply it to.

```
@media (max-width : 768px) {
    nav.affix {
        position: fixed;
        top: 0;
        width: 100%;
        z-index: 10;
    }
}
```

Comment: You're welcome man! If everything worked please mark as answered so it's removed from the unanswered queue.

Comment: There should be a checkmark image under the arrows on the left side of the answer, you click that. https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/147531/how-mark-my-question-as-answered-on-stackoverflow